# .Net Listbox will not compile with javascript event handler?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

This should be the simplest thing ever but it will not work. I have a simple asp.net Listbox and for the event OnSelectedIndexChanged I want to launch a javascript function. This works for when i set links to launch the same function but not when set for this particular control. The line of code is as follows:

```
<tr><td>
    <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" Width="250" 
    Height="600" OnSelectedIndexChanged="javascript:selectedIndexChanged()">
    </asp:ListBox>
</td></tr>
```

Here are the compilation errors i am getting:

> c:\..\ManufInfo.aspx(171,84): error
>   CS1026: ) expected
>   c:\..\ManufInfo.aspx(171,84): error
>   CS1002: ; expected
>   c:\..\ManufInfo.aspx(171,84): error
>   CS1525: Invalid expression term ':'
>   c:\..\ManufInfo.aspx(171,84): error
>   CS1026: ) expected
>   c:\..\ManufInfo.aspx(171,84): error
>   CS1002: ; expected
>   c:\..\ManufInfo.aspx(171,84): error
>   CS1525: Invalid expression term ':'
>   c:\..\ManufInfo.aspx(171,85): error
>   CS1002: ; expected
>   c:\..\ManufInfo.aspx(171,85): error
>   CS1002: ; expected
>   c:\..\ManufInfo.aspx(171,107): error
>   CS1002: ; expected
>   c:\..\ManufInfo.aspx(171,107): error
>   CS1525: Invalid expression term ')'
>   c:\..\ManufInfo.aspx(171,107): error
>   CS1002: ; expected
>   c:\..\ManufInfo.aspx(171,107): error
>   CS1525: Invalid expression term ')'

What the heck is going? ;) Probably a n00b mistake but I thought I was picking up jscript enough to understand that should work...

Thanks to anyone who can point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OnSelectedIndexChanged is not meant for javascript handlers. Try this on page_load

```
ListBox1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "selectedIndexChanged()");
```

Comment: Ah, so it was totally a n00b mistake. But I also accomplished it just by setting, <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" Width="250" Height="600" OnClick="javascript:selectedIndexChanged()">, is this not recommended?

Comment: The `OnClick` markup works on some controls.  Generally it's recommended to attach javascript functions in the code behind on page load so that you can use the ClientId for any control references that need to be used in the javascript.  It's more of a best practice because it's a good habit to develop, not a technical restriction that would apply to your specific example.

Answer (score 1):

The value that goes in the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` attribute must be the name of a method in the code-behind (or code-beside) that matches the signature of the `EventHandler` delegate, which is executed on post back.

SOE has provided the correct way to add a javascript onclick event to your control.

Answer (score 1):

This attribute is designed for ASP.Net events, not for clientside event handling.

You can attach an eventhandler after the control is rendered like this:

```
document.getElementById('<%=ListBox1.ClientID %>').onChange = function (){
    // your selectedIndexChanged logic goes here
};
```

Answer (score 1):

OnSelectedIndexChanged is server side. Will not trigger a javascript, it will refer to a codebehind method.